# How to combine `@dynamicMemberLookup` and `ExpressibleByStringInterpolation` to achieve method chaining?

Tags: swift, swift5

I have the following enum:

```swift
@dynamicMemberLookup
enum JSCall: ExpressibleByStringInterpolation {
    case getElement(String)
    case getInnerHTML(id: String)
    case removeAttribute(id: String, attributeName: String)
    case customScript(String)
    case document
    indirect case chainedCall(JSCall, String)

    var value: String {
        switch self {
        case .document:
            return "document"
        case .getElement(let id):
            return JSCall.chainedCall(.document, "getElementById('\(id)')").value
        case .getInnerHTML(let id):
            return JSCall.getElement(id).innerHTML.value // Using dynamic member lookup here
        case .removeAttribute(let id, let attribute):
            return JSCall.chainedCall(.getElement(id), "removeAttribute('\(attribute)')").value
        case .chainedCall(let prefixJs, let suffix):
            return "\(prefixJs.scriptString)\(STRING_DOT)\(suffix)"
        case .customScript(let script):
            return script
        }
    }

    init(stringLiteral value: String) {
        self = .customScript(value)
    }
    
    subscript(dynamicMember suffix: String) -> JSCall {
        return .chainedCall(.customScript(self.value), suffix)
    }
}
```

Notice that in computed property `value`, for `getInnerHTML` case, I could use a natural syntax for chaining .innerHTML via dot syntax, thanks to `@dynamicMemberLookup`. However, if I try chaining interpolated string like:

```swift
let call = JSCall.document.getElementById('\(id)').value
```

I am getting compiler error like *Cannot call value of non-function type 'JSCall'*.

I thought conforming to `ExpressibleByStringInterpolation` would solve the problem, but it didn't.

Is there any way to achieve natural syntax of chaining method calls in this enum ?

Comment: Is `CommonJS` supposed to be `JSCall`?

Comment: `dynamicMemberLookup` does not work with function calls, so this is to be expected.

Comment: Yeah I misspelt it as CommonJS

Comment: Is there any other way to achieve my goal with associated cases in enum @Sweeper ?

Comment: What exactly is your goal? Are you just trying to literally write JS in Swift, without using string literals?

Comment: I am not trying to write literal JS in Swift, but to provide a reusable wrapper for executing JS calls in WebView. I am thinking if `@dynamicCallable` will help with the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`dynamicMemberLookup` doesn't handle function calls. To be able to call a looked-up member, you can use `@dynamicCallable`. You can do something similar with `callAsFunction` too.

I think a simpler way to model this is to just have more "fundamental" cases, modelling the JS syntax tree.

```
@dynamicMemberLookup
@dynamicCallable
enum JSCall {
    case stringLiteral(String)
    case integerLiteral(Int)
    // add more literal cases if you like
    case call(String, args: [JSCall])
    case property(String)
    indirect case chain(JSCall, JSCall)

    var value: String {
        switch self {
        case let .call(functionName, args):
            let argList = args.map(\.value)
                .joined(separator: ", ")
            return "\(functionName)(\(argList))"
        case .property(let name):
            return name
        case .chain(let first, let second):
            return "\(first.value).\(second.value)"
        case .stringLiteral(let s):
            return "'\(s)'" // note that this does not escape quotes in the JS string!
        case .integerLiteral(let i):
            return "\(i)"
        }
    }

    // ...
}
```

When you look up a member dynamically, create a `chain` with the second thing being a `property`. This corresponds to cases like `foo.bar`

```
subscript(dynamicMember propertyName: String) -> JSCall {
    return .chain(self, .property(propertyName))
}
```

Then, in cases like `foo.bar("bar")`, you would implicitly invoke `(foo.bar).dynamicallyCall(withArguments: [.stringLiteral("baz")])`. This should return a `.chain(foo, .call("bar", [.stringLiteral("baz")]))`.

```
func dynamicallyCall(withArguments args: JSCall...) -> JSCall {
    switch self {
    case .property(let name):
        return .call(name, args: args)
    case .chain(let first, let second):
        // note the recursive call here:
        return .chain(first, second.dynamicallyCall(withArguments: args))
    default:
        fatalError("Cannot call this!")
    }
}
```

You can conform to `ExpressibleByXXXLiteral` for the literal cases:

```
extension JSCall: ExpressibleByStringLiteral, ExpressibleByIntegerLiteral {
    init(stringLiteral value: String) {
        self = .stringLiteral(value)
    }
    
    init(integerLiteral value: Int) {
        self = .integerLiteral(value)
    }
}
```

That's all the infrastructure. Now you can add some convenient static factories and properties:

```
static let document = JSCall.property("document")

static func getElement(_ id: String) -> JSCall {
    document.getElementById(.stringLiteral(id))
}

static func getInnerHTML(_ id: String) -> JSCall {
    getElement(id).innerHTML
}

static func removeAttribute(id: String, attributeName: String) -> JSCall {
    getElement(id).removeAttribute(.stringLiteral(attributeName))
}
```

Usage:

```
let one = JSCall.document.getElementById("foo").value
let two = JSCall.removeAttribute(id: "bar", attributeName: "attr").somethingElse.value
print(one) // document.getElementById('foo')
print(two) // document.getElementById('bar').removeAttribute('attr').somethingElse
```

Comment: This solution is fine. Just curious to know if `@dynamicCallable` will help in this case

Comment: @Kris2k `dynamicCallable` should work as well. The code should be quite similar.

Comment: Okay I will try it out

Comment: @Kris2k I've edited to use `dynamicCallable` instead.